# Re-learning basics of trigonometric functions to solve $2\cos(x+10º) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm helping my daughter with her math homework. It's been 25 years since I learned this myself. What do I need to re-learn about trigonometric functions to solve: $$2\cos(x+10º)=1$$

Comment: By the way, write **\cos** to generate $\cos$ as opposed to $cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2\cos(x+10º) = 1$$
$$\cos(x+10º) = \frac 12$$
You have to remember that $\cos(60)=\cos(-60)=1/2$
$$\cos(x+10º) = \cos(60)$$
$$x+10=60$$
$$x=50°$$

And
$$\cos(x+10º) = \cos(-60)$$
$$x+10=-60$$
$$x=-70°$$
$$x=360-70=290°$$

These are the solutions to the equation in the interval $[0,360]$ as Taussig has pointed out...

Comment: These are the solutions in the interval $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$.

Comment: yes @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1):

Write your equation as $$\cos(x+10^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}$$ substitute $$t=x+10^{\circ}$$ and you have to solve $$\cos(t)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to relearn the trig tables and associated inverse trig tables.

To solve your question ;

$2\cos(x+10^{\circ}) = 1$

$\cos(x+10^{\circ})=\frac12$

$x+10^\circ = \arccos(\frac12)$

$x= 60^\circ-10^\circ $

$x = 50^\circ$  $\quad$ if $x\in \{0,\pi\} $

more generally,

$x=2n\pi\pm50^\circ$ $\quad$ for any $n\in Z$

Comment: You missed a few solutions.

Comment: @UmbertoP. true, there are infinitely many solutions.  Many times though the problem writers ask only for the solution between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thank you,i have edited accordingly. I had ignored the periodicity of $\cos$ and restricted the answer from $0$ to $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
2\cos(x+10) &= 1 \qquad &\text{given}\\
\cos(x+10) &= 1/2 \qquad &\text{try to isolate the trig function}\\
x+10 &= \arccos(1/2) \qquad &\text{use the inverse trig function}\\
x+10 &=60, -60 \qquad &\text{consider unit circle to check for multiple values}\\
x&= 50, -70 (\text{ or $290$)} \qquad &\text{solve for $x$}
\end{align}

Note that $\cos(t) = 1/2$ has two solution sets: $60 + 2\pi \cdot k$ and $-60 + 2\pi \cdot k$ where $k$ is an integer value. This is because $\cos(t)$ is periodic. I have only included the solutions from the domain $[0, 360]$

Comment: Be careful:  $360^\circ - 70^\circ = 290^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1):

You should use the general solution.

You have $$\cos(x+10)=\frac 12$$
$$\implies x+10=\pm60+n\cdot360$$
$$\implies x=50\;\text{or}-70+n\cdot360$$